# Trying to find the source of a <video> tag using C#

Tags: c#, html, video

I am currently trying to get the source of a 'video' tag on a website using C#, I am using HtmlAgilityPack and have not yet found a way to make this possible, any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The home page for [HAP](http://html-agility-pack.net/) shows [C# HTML Selectors Examples](http://html-agility-pack.net/selectors) look at the `SelectSingleNode(String)` method and then use `Attributes` collection on the returned node to get the value for `src`.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/bsfYsg